# How to ask user if he/she wants to quit the program and print out the thank you message in Java

Tags: java

I am taking the first Java class and working on my second project. The project is about creating an program as a network of rooms on a virtual three-dimensional work area. Each room provides a virtual environment that together can be assemble into a simulated or virtual world.
Basically, the beginning of the program, I used while loop, and at the end I want to ask user if he/she wants to quit the program, and print a thank you message. However, the while loop does not work. My program quit no matter I entered y or n. Below is my codes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Project 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Map map = new Map();
    int floor = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    String input = " ";
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Begin user dialog. Welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the L.A Underground! (Verson 1.1)");
    System.out.println();
    
    String choice = "y";
    while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
    {
      input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    // My codes are here
   if (input.equals("south")
        {statement}
            else
                System.out.println("You can't go that way.");

   else if (input.equals("quit"))
        {   // See if user wants to continue
        System.out.println("Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)? >");
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        }
   // if user enters other words than quit
    else
        System.out.println("I don't recognize the word '" + input +"'");
      }
       System.out.println("Thank you for visiting L.A Underground.");
    }
  }
```

When I typed "quit" the console printed the message: "Do you wish to leave the Underground? (Y/N)? >". I tried Y/N (y/n) the program terminated. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Updated:** Sorry for the confusion. What I wanted the program to run is when the user types "quit", the message will print out "Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)?>?" , and if the user types "hello", the message will be "I don't understand the word 'hello'". And when the user type y, the program will quit, otherwise (type n), the program will start over again.

Comment: Not sure if the program above is correct . I fo not see an IF for the ELSE i just see the comment  // if user enters other words than quit. I do not see you doing anything with the value in the variable choice .  I mean in your code ystem.out.println("Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)? >");
            choice = scan.nextLine();   What are you doing with the value in choice

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Please format your code. It's got an extra closing bracket. And an `else if` without a preceding `if`. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Also, as @AlbertPinto said, you've asked for y/n, but you aren't doing anything with it.

Comment: @AlbertPinto Sorry for the confusion. I just edited my codes. Hope it will clarify your thoughts. And could you please explain more your idea of what I should do with the value in the variable choice? Thanks!

Comment: @gldraphael thank you for the welcome message! I just edited my code. I accidentally deleted the preceding "if" before posting. I just learn Java recently, so I might confuse with my presentation. hope you understand. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you've posted, your loop is being controlled by the condition `!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")`. That is, if `input` is "quit", the loop is terminated.

But the following block is executed only if `input` is "quit":

```
if (input.equals("quit"))
{   
    // See if user wants to continue
    System.out.println("Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)? >");
    choice = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
}
```

So if this block is executed, `!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")` evaluates to `false` and the loop is terminated. And that's not what you want.

Now that you know what's wrong, fixing it is easy. Check the value of `choice` in the above `if` block: if `choice` is not yes, don't quit i.e. reset `input` to a default value.

I've pasted the working code [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/v4uyv12f).

[image]

Comment: OMG.. Thank you! It works now. I forgot to check the value of choice as you and @Albert Pino said before. Thanks again! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for user input inside of your loop. If `input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")`, then prompt the user an "are you sure" message. If the `input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")`, then `break` the loop, otherwise, keep going.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    // Begin user dialog. Welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the L.A Underground! (Verson 1.1)");
    System.out.println();

    while (true) {
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.out.print("Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)? >");
            if (scan.nextLine().equals("y")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // input wasn't "quit", so do other stuff here
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for visiting L.A Underground.");
```

Comment: Eloson: Thanks for your help! I tried to apply it on my codes but it did not work. I did not know why the while loop does not work. Other than that, my program runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code loops until it gets "quit" ... then asks for "yes/no" ... then simply exits, regardless.

You need to change your loop, so that it includes *BOTH* "MY CODES HERE" *AND* the "quit y/n" check.

EXAMPLE:

```
...
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
  //MY CODES ARE HERE
  if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") && getYesNo ()) == 'y') {
    done = true;
  }
}
```

"getYesNo()" is a method you write.  For example:

```
char getYesNo () {
  System.out.print("Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)? >");
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  return line.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: @pausm4: Thanks for your help. However, what I wanted the program to run is when the user types "quit", the message will print out "Do you wish to leave the Underground (Y/N)?>?" , and if the user types "hello", the message will be "I don't understand the word 'hello'". And when the user type y, the program will quit, otherwise (type n), the program will start over again.

Comment: 1) The program already prompts the user for "quit".  2) If you want to say "I don't understand" until you get either "y" or "n", then simply loop inside of `getYesNo()` until "line.equalsIgnoreCase("y") or "n" :)